# ATI and NVIDIA card in same motherboard for CUDA

Tags: graphics-card, amd-radeon, nvidia-geforce, cuda

I want to run an HD6990 and a GTX 460 in the same machine, using the HD6990 for gaming and the 460 for CUDA - not for display.

Is this feasible? I am running Windows 7

Comment: What operating system? (Be as specific as you can.)

Comment: Yes, it's feasible. I don't do it, only hear, read and see - thus just comment, not answer. Yesterday I got dual-GPU (both NVidia) systems working with separation of view and CUDA-PhysX - your actions will quite noticeable  match with my

Comment: @david-schwartz - I think "gaming" and "HD6990" in one sentence almost *automagically* means Windows. Looking at the calendar, I presume Windows7 or, for die-hard  gamers - XP SP3

Comment: @LazyBadger: Windows 7 and Windows XP have completely different video driver architectures. The answers for Windows 7 would be completely different from the answers for Windows XP.

Comment: [Topic one](http://www.overclock.net/graphics-cards-general/508305-howto-ati-nvidia-physx-guide.html) and [topic two](http://forums.guru3d.com/showthread.php?t=284463), both Seven-centric, confirm **my** vision from **user's POV**

Answer (score -1):

It will either ruin the motherboard or just won't run.

If you want it to work, the cards have to be of same series 69XX series. It can be different brands though they can be amd and the other can be powercolor but you can't mix nvidia with ATI or AMD.

Comment: Actually you can mix them; your answer is incorrect

Comment: Remember the good old days when everything was compatible with everything?